# count how many first columns in each table

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have 2 tables, first table have 2 columns and the second table have 3 columns, i using ckeditor so i dont know how to add diferent class name. so in this tables  have class name 'table'. i want to count how many first columns in each table and give wrap class if first columns> 2, so far my code is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.prosiding-content iframe').wrap('<div class="map-responsive"></div>');
      // $('.prosiding-content table').wrap('<div class="table-responsive"> </div>');
      $('.prosiding-content table').addClass('table');

      $('.prosiding-content img').addClass('img-responsive');

var table= $(".prosiding-content table").find("td:first").length;

if (table>2) {
  $(this).wrap('<div class="table-responsive"> </div>');
}

  });
</script>
```

[image: here is my table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just count columns inside any existing row (assuming that a table has the same column count inside rows) and add a required class.

```js
var tables = editor.editable().find( 'table' ).toArray();

CKEDITOR.tools.array.forEach( tables, function( table ) {
  var header = table.findOne( 'tr' );

  if ( header && header.getChildCount() > 2 ) {
    table.addClass( 'multiple-columns' );
  }
} );
```

Please use https://codepen.io/jacekbogdanski/pen/xzVYXL codepen for working example.